# How to use diffForHumans() with laravel view

Tags: laravel

I need to use diffForHumans() function in laravel blade file

I have use a data array to echo the data in blade view {{$data['time']}}

```
{{$data['time']}}
```

i expect the out is 2 minutes ago .

Comment: What does your `$data['time']` returns? Is it a `Carbon` instance?

Comment: @nakov It's return 2019-06-18 05:41:45

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
// in your view add this
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($data['time'])->diffForHumans() }}

// or when you prepare your $data array in the controller or wherever
$data['time'] = $model->created_at->diffForHumans();
```

Answer (score 1):

if the `$data['time']` is an instance of carbon u can basically do `{{$data['time']->diffForHumans()}}`